# Renaming EC2 instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2

Ive got a few EC2 instances which need to be renamed so that they follow a naming convention.
Is it just a matter of editing the name in EC2? Or is there something else I would need to do? Does this cause any issues with the machine id name, DNS etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can rename an EC2 instance by editing the "Name" tag on your EC2 instance.

If a Name tag does not exist and your EC2 is currently nameless, you can just create a new tag with key "Name".
[image]

Answer (score 4):

> **Is it just a matter of editing the name in EC2 ?**

Yes. As long as you just need an helpful name for your EC2 instances, you can just edit their names in your EC2 management console. It will not have any effect on your machine id name nor your DNS

Comment: Explanation: The name that appears in the Amazon EC2 management console is simply the Tag called `Name`. It is purely provided for human use and is not used by the Amazon EC2 system itself.